# Node-Webkit о железе

Tags: node.js, gpu, jquery, cpu, c++

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно средствами node-webkit узнать такие параметры, как название ноутбука (acer, asus, lenovo etc и т.д.), модель (x553ma, Aspire 5750ZG и т.д.), размер жесткого диска, наличие модуля Wifi, bluetooth, видеокарты. С помощью os.cpus() смог только узнать модель процессора и количество `озу. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: если под линукс - то запускайте dmidecode или lshw и парсите вывод.

Comment: Вот бы знать, как это сделать...